# Origen y significado de la expresión "el miedo no anda en burro"

Tags: méxico, modismos, refranes

Viendo hoy El Chapulín Colorado, un rival del héroe le mencionaba

> El miedo no anda en burro, ¿verdad, Chapulín?

Me picó la curiosidad la frase (a pesar que es como la enésima vez que veo el capítulo) y al consultar, aparece una [película de 1976](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_miedo_no_anda_en_burro) con ese título.

El [resultado](https://brainly.lat/tarea/6563180) de la búsqueda rápida en internet no termina de convencerme (que el miedo es algo muy rápido...) y me queda la duda de cómo surgió la expresión (la adjudico como mexicanismo, pues no recuerdo haberla visto, oído o leído en otras zonas hispanohablantes).

Valga agregar que la expresión parece *reciente*, pues según Google Ngrams aparece en 1923 por primera vez (buscando solo "miedo no anda en burro" pues el máximo es de 5 palabras)

Comment: Aqui la respuesta: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27027/origen-y-significado-de-la-expresi%C3%B3n-el-miedo-no-anda-en-burro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Su primer aparición he encontrado es en una revista mexicana de 1913:

> «El miedo no anda en burro» dice un proverbio vulgar...
>
> - [*Cosmos Magazine*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4gswAAAAYAAJ&q=%22anda+en+burro%22), (1913)

Una explicación se da aquí:

> #### El miedo no anda en burro.
>
> Quien es amenazado por un peligro debe huir rápidamente. De otro modo sería tanto como montar en un burro, que es un animal cansino y lento.
>
> - [*Refranero popular mexicano*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Mq47M1aX77cC&pg=PA101&dq=%22anda+en+burro%22), Max Mendizábal (p.101) (2005)

---

Usar la expression "andar en burro" en sí mismo para decir "mover lentamente" es (comprensiblemente) aún más antiguo:

> No andar en burro.
>   Sino correr
>   Como un demonio
>   Por un express;
>
> [*La musa festiva de Samuel*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dI8SAAAAYAAJ&q="no+andar+en+burro"), Luis G. Ledesma (1887)

Comment: Resulta al menos curioso que se hable de un *express* en 1887

Answer (score 1):

Esa frase hizo muy popular por una película de "la india maria" una película de comedia/horror

Esta frase resulta ser una apología de la actitud que toma alguien asustado.

> ¿por que salio corriendo?
>   pues por que el miedo no anda en burro!

y como muchos refranes y dichos mexicanos, debió haber surgido de algún suceso chusco que la gente adoptó y no tuvo alta difusión hasta el final de los 70's.

En mis viajes por mexico esta frase resulta mucho mas popular en el interior y sur de la república que en el norte. por lo que me inclinaria a que sus origen "vulgar" se inclina por la demografía de esa zona, aunque tal vez haya tenido origen en otro lugar. Muchos cineastas mexicanos tanto de la época del oro y plata del cine mexicano han tenido su inspiración precisamente de escuchar y conocer costumbres a lo largo y ancho del país.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora que lo analizo, me parece bastante prudente la referencia a huir de algo amenazante o una situación incómoda, no obstante puede interpretarse lo siguiente: si consideramos al Burro un animal tonto, que esto no es que así lo piense, sino más bien proviene de épocas antiguas escolares donde para castigar a los niños se les colocaban unas orejas de burro para ridiculizarlos, por motivo de su falta de conocimiento, se supone que este animal el Burro es un ser, que no tiene miedo en lo que involucra a su integridad física, por ejemplo en un incendio un Burro puede pasar por una línea muy cercana sin problemas, en contraste con un caballo que respondería a huir del sitio, por ello la frase: El miedo no anda en Burro, es indicando que si no tienes miedo es porque eres tonto, y que el que tiene miedo no es ningún tonto huyendo de la situación que le muestra peligro.